# Delete MySQL record via jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I cannot figure out why this code will not work.  I would like to be able to click the delete button in the adminSLP page and when i do it will bring up a confirm dialog.  After that if the user clicks ok it will delete the record from the database.

Is there a simpler solution or something I am missing?  Also the table I am trying to delete from is `users` and it has the id column of `user_id`.

### adminSLP

```
<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

### jquery

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var user_id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + user_id;
    if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: info,
    success: function(){
    }
    });
    $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
    });
```

### delete.php

```
<?php
// Initializing connection data.
$host_db = 'DB';
$name_db = 'NAME';
$user_db = 'USER';
$pass_db = '*******';

// Connecting using the PDO object.
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$name_db", $user_db, $pass_db);

// Setting the query and runnin it...

$states = "SELECT * FROM license_state";
$array = array();
$result = $connection->query($select);
if(!isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $sql= "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=$user_id";
    $result=mysqli_query($sql,$connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: You should probably change your MySQL connection credentials now.

Comment: I've seen it today already and I'll say it again here. You're mixing MySQL APIs and they don't mix. This isn't rum & coke. You're connecting with PDO and using an `mysqli_` function. Add `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened; then out will POP your errors.

Comment: Nice connection details...

Comment: In short, PDO requires an [execute function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) in order to process your query and not `mysqli_query()`. That or change your DB connection to `mysqli_`, it's your choice.

Comment: Also ... you're setting $id, but use $user_id in query. Also be careful because of sql injection!

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

**delete.php**

```
...
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_db; dbname=$name_db", $user_db, $pass_db);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id";
    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Your code is so messy. You should read all comments on your question as it would help you writing better code later. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I add that it might be good to use several layers of php for a better code maintenance. See N-Tiers architecture.